# Amazon EC2 instance “sudo reboot” not coming back up

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2

I did a "sudo reboot" on my EC2 CentOS and now my instance is not coming back up! It is a web server and I know there is nothing wrong with my configs to make it not come back up! The only thing I did not know is that in the future, it is better to reboot through EC2 console and not through OS level.

Did I lose everything? How can I bring it back up? Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: instance size ? syslog output ? disk storage type ? service status checks ? need way more information.

Comment: here is a screenshot to my log "http://i.imgur.com/ReRVLdU.png" it is basically a fresh CentOS instance as a webserver. my status check is 1/2 "Instance reachability check failed..."

Comment: I would have just created a new one, but my MySQL is there and I have new entries that I need :(

Comment: if one of the two status checks has failed, try stopping the instance, then starting it again. that sometimes works for me on a few of my instances. Needless to say, regular snapshots are a god send.

Comment: Don't worry - even if the OS is dead, you can start a new EC2 instance and mount the dead OS volume in the new instance, then backup MySQL.